# executeAction fails saying functionality does not exist from code ported from scriptListener

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

New to photoshop scripting but am well versed in JS. I'm trying to build a script to create gifs. Had most of it written but discovered you can't access the timeline animation stuff via JS and have to use script listener.

Problem I'm running into is that even though I recorded and copied the scriptListener code creating the animations in timeline the scriptListener code always fails

> Photoshop executeAction Error: "This functionality may not be
>   available in this version of Photoshop"

Which doesn't make since since I'm recording from the same version of Photoshop (CC-2017) that I'm running the extendScript code in.

Am I just integrating the scriptListener code in the wrong way or what?

Comment: Is it all scriptlistener code? Can you narrow it down to which part of the scriptlistener code it fails on? Most of the time SL code works fine, unless you do something out of sequence.

Comment: So the part that breaks is definitely all script listener code. It's everytime the executeAction function is called. Fails every time with that same error as above.

Comment: As ugly as scriptlistener code is, can you include the code as part of your question.